# Collapsing several "required field missing" errors down to one line in the "stripes:errors" box

Tags: validation, jsp, stripes

I realize this is kind of "Stripes 101", but I guess I skipped that class.

I'd like to use the code that drops the "error" class into the field
tag class strings as the primary way to indicate missing required
fields. I'd then like to show a single error message along with any
other errors (like fields supplied with improper values).

Thus, the error info on the page might look like:

> Sorry for the trouble, but:

```
 1. Please supply values for all indicated required fields.
 2. Please supply a numeric value for Zip Code.
```

etc.

I suppose I could go through the validation errors, look for ones for
fields where the value is empty, and make the assumption that those
were the required field errors.  However, if I take those errors out
of the set, then I suspect that the page will no longer be able to
mark the erroneously-missing fields with the "error" class.

This seems like something likely to be pretty easy, but I can't find
any specific examples. Maybe I can do it all in the .jsp code; I'll start looking into that.

Answer (score 1):

The `DefaultActionBeanPropertyBinder` adds an instance of `ScopedLocalizableError` with the default scope value of "validation.required" when a required field is missing.

So you coult probably write a tag similar to the stripes errors tag, but which collapes all the instances of ScopedLocalizableError having a default scope of "validation.required" to a single error message.

Comment: Yes that would probably work. For now, a "solution" involving having the jsp page (there's just one in this test app for now) figure things out from the ValidationErrors map will work. Your solution would obviously be far better.